# Search for a string in javascript and delete it with splice and index nr

Tags: javascript

I am new to js, I have an array that I need to convert to an object, and then I need to search for a string, and then delete that string.

The first part I can solve of converting a array to an object, I can also search for a string.

The part I can't solve is to retrieve the index nr of the string I searched for and then for example use splice to delete that string in the array.

Here is my code:

```
let todoList = ['Order dog food', 'Clean kitchen', 'Buy food', 'Do homework', 'Exercise']

function strings_to_object(array) {

    // Initialize new empty array
    let objects = [];


    // Loop through the array
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        // Create the object in the format you want
        let obj = {"Task" : array[i]};

        // Add it to the array
        objects.push(obj);
    }

    // Return the new array
    return objects;
}

//Add additional properties
let Todo = strings_to_object(todoList)
Todo[0].status = 'done'
Todo[1].status = 'done'
Todo[2].status = 'standby'
Todo[3].status = 'done'
Todo[4].status = 'standby'

console.log(Todo)

//function to find a string in the array
const findTodo = function (todos, todoTitle) {
    const index = todos.findIndex(function (todo, index) {
        return todo.toLowerCase() === todoTitle.toLowerCase()
    })
    return todoList[index]
}

//Call the function to find the string and provide the string
const todo = findTodo(todoList, 'CLean kitchen')

console.log(`You searched for: ${todo}`)
```

This is the output:

```
[ { Task: 'Order dog food', status: 'done' },
  { Task: 'Clean kitchen', status: 'done' },
  { Task: 'Buy food', status: 'standby' },
  { Task: 'Do homework', status: 'done' },
  { Task: 'Exercise', status: 'standby' } ]
You searched for: Clean kitchen
```

So in the example above, I would like to find the index nr for the string 'Clean kitchen' and then use splice to delete it.
thanks

Comment: you can use `Array.splice(index, 1);` to delete an element at that index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can return index from your findTodo and then splice the todoList Array using index in splice

```js
let todoList = ['Order dog food', 'Clean kitchen', 'Buy food', 'Do homework', 'Exercise']

function strings_to_object(array) {

    // Initialize new empty array
    let objects = [];


    // Loop through the array
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        // Create the object in the format you want
        let obj = {"Task" : array[i]};

        // Add it to the array
        objects.push(obj);
    }

    // Return the new array
    return objects;
}

//Add additional properties
let Todo = strings_to_object(todoList)
Todo[0].status = 'done'
Todo[1].status = 'done'
Todo[2].status = 'standby'
Todo[3].status = 'done'
Todo[4].status = 'standby'
console.log("Orginal Todo");
console.log(Todo)

//function to find a string in the array
const findTodo = function (todos, todoTitle) {
    const index = todos.findIndex(function (todo, index) {
        return todo.toLowerCase() === todoTitle.toLowerCase()
    })
    return index;  // Returning Index of Element
}

//Call the function to find the string and provide the string
const todoIndex = findTodo(todoList, 'CLean kitchen')   // Getting Index

//console.log(`You searched for: CLean Kitchen and found at index ${todoIndex}`)
todoList.splice(todoIndex,1);   // Splicing array using index
console.log("todoList after splicing array");
console.log(todoList);
deleteFromObject("CLean kitchen");    // Delete Object from Todo
console.log("Todo after splicing object[] ");
console.log(Todo);


function deleteFromObject(todoTitle){
  for(let i=0;i<Todo.length;i++){
    if(Todo[i].Task.toLowerCase() == todoTitle.toLowerCase()){
        Todo.splice(i,1);   // Delete Object
    }
  }
}
```

is That what you want

Comment: Thanks, I got stuck on this for a while :)

Comment: I was wondering, is it possible to display the object with all the tasks and their status minus the deleted array, instead of just the array list?

Comment: @user2371684 i have added a function called deleteFromObject it will delete the value from object . Run the Code Snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
const findTodo = function (todos, todoTitle) {
    const index = todos.findIndex(function (todo, index) {
        return todo.toLowerCase() === todoTitle.toLowerCase()
    })
    return todoList[index]
}
```

when you are returning the found string instead of returning the string create a object with both found string and the index like below

```
const findTodo = function (todos, todoTitle) {
        const index = todos.findIndex(function (todo, index) {
            return todo.toLowerCase() === todoTitle.toLowerCase()
        })

        return {index:index,foundString:todoList[index]}
    }
```

so that when you call this function you can use it like this

```
const todo = findTodo(todoList, 'CLean kitchen')

console.log(`You searched for: ${todo.foundString} which is at ${todo.index}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const newArray = todos.filter(function (todo) {
     return todo["Task"].toLowerCase() != todoTitle.toLowerCase()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this Code,

```
function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
        for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
            if (strArray[j].Task.match(str)) return j;
        }
        return -1;
    }
var count = searchStringInArray("Clean kitchen", obj);
obj.splice(count, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to find and delete the index

```
  function searchAndDelete(nameKey, myArray){
   for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].Task.includes(nameKey)) {
         console.log(i)
         myArray.splice(i,1)

    }
}
return myArray;}
```

and then you can call it as

```
searchAndDelete("Clean",yourArray)
```